# The property 'documents' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart, null

I'm having issues with my code. I keep getting these errors of The property 'documents' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').dart(unchecked_use_of_nullable_value). I have tried all I could. but to no avail. Any advice on what to do? I'm trying to get data from firebase in real time. Here's my code.

```dart
                  import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
                  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
                  import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
                  import '../services/crud.dart';
                  import '../views/createBlog.dart';

                  class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
                    @override
                    _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
                  }

                  class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
                    CrudMethods crudMethods = new CrudMethods();

                    Stream? blogStream;

                    Widget BlogsList() {
                      return Container(
                        child: blogStream != null
                            ? Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  StreamBuilder(
                                    stream: blogStream,
                                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                                      return ListView.builder(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                                        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                                        shrinkWrap: true,
                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                          return BlogsTile(
                                            imgUrl: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['imgUrl'],
                                            author:
                                                snapshot.data.documents[index].data['authorName'],
                                            title: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['title'],
                                            desc: snapshot.data.documents[index].data['desc'],
                                          );
                                        },
                                      );
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ],
                              )
                            : Container(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                              ),
                      );
                    }

                    @override
                    void initState() {
                      super.initState();

                      crudMethods.getData().then((result) {
                        setState(() {
                          blogStream = result;
                        });
                      });
                    }

                    @override
                    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                      return Scaffold(
                        appBar: AppBar(
                          title: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Text(
                                "Fooz",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 22,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                "Blog",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 22,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.blue),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                          elevation: 0.0,
                        ),
                        body: BlogsList(),
                        floatingActionButton: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FloatingActionButton(
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateBlog()),
                              ),
                              child: Icon(
                                Icons.add,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                              backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }

                  class BlogsTile extends StatelessWidget {
                    String imgUrl, desc, author, title;
                    BlogsTile({
                      required this.imgUrl,
                      required this.author,
                      required this.title,
                      required this.desc,
                    });
                    @override
                    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15),
                        height: 170,
                        child: Stack(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: imgUrl,
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 170,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.black45.withOpacity(0.3),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    title,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 22,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 4,
                                  ),
                                  Text(
                                    desc,
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                                  ),
                                  SizedBox(
                                    height: 4,
                                  ),
                                  Text("Author: $author"),
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }
```

[image: This is the error I receive in the image]

Comment: What the error says is that `snapshot.data` can be `null` , it's best you make a check before accessing it, `if (snapshot.hasData) {}`. Then you can always strip the `nullability` by adding a `!` like so `snapshot.data!`

Comment: If statement returns error on the the said line.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is nullable and the property can't be assigned with a null value, you can use a [null-aware (??) operator](https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet#null-aware-operators) to set a default value if the nullable value is null.

Let's say the document length can be null, we can set `0` as the default length.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length ?? 0,
  ...
),
```

Similarly, this can be applied when assigning property values to `BlogsTile`.